# How to implement the Azure Search services through the ajax without using controller in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to access the azure search services using REST API URL in ajax i am getting like network error/CORS Header missing:

```
SyntaxError: Json.Parse: unexpected end of data at aline 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
```

Can you help me how to use the azure search services using only ajax(without controller)

If we can do means can you tell me the what are the site and user detail i have to pass with ajax control

Can you please mention the syntax for ajax calling for access the Azure search services

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://{site-name}.search.windows.net/indexes/temp/docs?api-version=2015-02-28-Preview&search=metrics1-",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
        'Host': '{site-name}.search.windows.net',
    headers: {
        "api-key": "{api-key}",
        "odata.metadata": "none",
    },
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert("Search Result" + data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        debugger;
        alert("Search Result" + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explanatory. If you can't help yourself first, why you expect others to help you? Please describe **what you have tried* until now to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

In order to make AJAX calls for performing search against your Search Service Index, you would need to configure CORS and allow your origin (your website address) there. You can do it through Azure Portal.

Just select your Index and then click on "Edit CORS Options" button. On the subsequent blade, provide the address of your website or you can choose "All" in "Select origin type".

[image]

Once you do this, you should not get this error.